# React Native SetTimeOut

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, react-native

I want to use timer within my RN apps. I want to show `waiting...` message top of the list view. Here is the scenario, wait 2.5 second for adding new item to list, at the same time show info message to user, then wait 1 seconds for next cycle and don't show `waiting...` message. How can I do this? I tried many combination but it never works as expected.

```
render(){
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.waiting}>
              {'waiting...'}
            </Text>
            <ListView
              dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
              renderRow={this.renderCell}
              automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
              style={styles.listView}
              />
          </View>
        );
      }
```

Comment: OP should give some credit to the answers. I believe the answers weren't so bad that they got a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, give it a try this code. Hope this help...

```
getInitialState: function() {
   return {
     showLoading : true,//To show 'Waiting Text in initial state.
   };
},

componentDidMount() {
   this.setTimeout( () => {
      this._hideLoadingView();//To hide 'Waiting' Text after 1 second
   },1000);
},

_hideLoadingView() {
   this.setState({
     showLoading: false, //set state to hide 'Waiting'
   });
},


render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this._loadingTextView()}
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderCell}
          automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
          style={styles.listView}
          />
      </View>
    );
  },

_loadingTextView(){
  if(this.state.showLoading){//To show or hide 'Waiting'
  return( 
     <Text style={styles.waiting}>
     Waiting.....
     </Text>
   )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Phyo is almost right. The only problem being that it will happpen only once. I will not cycle between the two. The following might get the trick done

```
getInitialState: function() {
   return {
     showLoading : true,//To show 'Waiting Text in initial state.
   };
},

 componentWillMount() {
  this._showLoadingView; // start by displaying the wait
},

_hideLoadingView() {
   this.setTimeout(this._showLoadingView,1000);
   this.setState({
     showLoading: false, //set state to hide 'Waiting'
   });
},
_showLoadingView(){
   // Do other fetch instructions here
   this.setTimeout(this._hideLoadingView,2500);
   this.setState({
     showLoading: true,
   });
},
render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.textRender()}
        <ListView
         dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
         renderRow={this.renderCell}
         automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
         style={styles.listView}
         />
      </View>
    );
  },

textRender(){
  if(this.state.showLoading){//To show or hide 'Waiting'
      return( 
         <Text style={styles.waiting}>
             Waiting.....
         </Text>
       )
  }
  else{
      return <View />
  }

}
```

Remember to use the TimerMixin if you want to use this.setTimeout (recommended) else use setTimeout

Comment: Ok but I dont want to return new View, Text and ListView both are should be same view. I want to change something like `this.setState({waiting: 'waiting...'});` or `this.setState({waiting: ''});`

Comment: In that case the text will scroll away as the list view grows. This will ensure that the waiting is in the top like a header. Also returning a empty view will not affect the experience

Comment: Text is not in the listview.

Comment: you could also have a look at look at listview's headerView.

Comment: If you return a null text instead of a null view, the textView would retain it's styling, with a null text. I guess you're not expecting this